# Choosing geometry to store tin format data to support spatial queries?

Tags: postgis, 3d, tin

What is the best way to store 3D TIN data in postgis, to support queries like st_intersects, st_within, st_overlaps, etc. I can't use TIN since it only supports st_intersects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are now 3D functions in Postgis, including [ST_3DIntersects](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html). Postgis supports **TINs** natively, via the SFGCAL extension, which you can install with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_sfcgal;
```

with Postgis 2.2 or above.

This [Postgis blog](http://postgis.net/2015/10/25/postgis_sfcgal_extension/) article gives some more detailed explanations. Here is a link to [the sfgcal project](http://www.sfcgal.org/) -- the Postgis functions are just a wrapper around the sfcgal functions, works which was done by

So now, going back to **ST_3DIntersects** and **TINs**, from the docs, you can write a query like:

```
SELECT ST_3DIntersects(
      'TIN(((0 0,1 0,0 1,0 0)))', 
      'POINT(.1 .1)');
```

and the geometry datatype supports TINs natively, as well as Polyhedral surfaces.

You can easily extend this to 3D:

```
SELECT ST_3DIntersects(
     'TIN(((0 0 0,1 0 0,0 1 1,0 0 0)))', 
     'POINT(.1 .1 .1)');
```

**Note:** In order for TINs to be recognized, you either have to preface your query with:

```
set postgis.backend = sfcgal;
```

or, better, set it at the database level:

```
ALTER DATABASE <your_db> SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;
```

which will require you to log out and back in again from your terminal session (this is true with psql on linux, anyway).

I don't usually give book recommendations, and I am in no way connected to the authors, but I came across this outstanding book [Postgis Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849518666), which has some very good chapters on 2.5 and 3D functionality, pointclouds, and a few other things for which it is harder to find documentation.

Finally, again no association, but I think is fair to mention [oslandia](http://oslandia.com/en/home-en/) who apparently did all the work to make **sfgcal** available to Postgis. The ability to do raster, vector, 3D, all inside the DB is making Postgis astonishingly powerful.

Comment: Thanks a lot John Powell for the info.I would definitely check the book. I would install SFGCAL and try to ran those queries. Before this post, I referred to one Boundless article that lists which all functionalities are available with 3D TIN data. And I found the basic queries that I want to handle are not supported for TIN, so started looking for other data type.(https://connect.boundlessgeo.com/docs/suite/4.5/postgis/postgis/html/PostGIS_Special_Functions_Index.html#PostGIS_PS_GeometryFunctions)